# lognormal distribution 'won't fit'

Tags: distributions, fitting, lognormal-distribution

my problem is the following.

I am measuring relative fluxs over time, so a relative light curve. Relative here means that I am measuring the flux relative to the median, i.e. the median deviation.

I *know* that the absolute flux distribution should be approximated by a log normal distribution.

I therefor computed absolute fluxes as a function of a set of medians (mu) and variances (sig):

- For every mu I compute an absolute light curve  L(mu)
- I than compute the detection frequency in the following way
- f_k =  sum(number of times the flux is in the bin)/(binwidth*number of observations) This ensures that the integral over the histogram is 1 even for uneven binwidths
- I than compute the bin widths as a function of mu:

  - bin1 =  mu +- DL # here every measurement below detection limit (DL)
  - bin2 =  everything that is above the detection limit
- the corresponding bin width therefor is width1 =  2*DL+mu, width2 = max(L(mu))-(DL+mu)

For mu = 0:
[image]
For mu = 0.5:
[image]
Description:
x-axis is the Flux; y-axis is the detectionFrequency. The blue line connecting the data points are the measured histogram point: detectionFrequency(mu). The PDFs plotted below are the lognormal distributions for a given mu, with a set of sigmas ranging from 0 to 3.0.

Note:

a) I am not plotting the bin width

b) The slope of the histogram inverts at some value of mu. This is because the bin-width width1 increases with mu, where as the width2 stays constant.
For all combinations of mu and sigma the distribution **never** fits (I checked a wide range of values, not only the ones displayed).

---

Without the plotted lognormal distributions it seams pretty easy to imaging a lognormal distribution that fits the distribution. I assume  that my error (or at least my guess of my error) is that I am not understanding the step from PDF(x), where x is an arbitrary random variable, and PDF(F(mu)) where F(mu) is a physical quantity.

---

Pseudo code for the generation of the plots

```
load lightcurve 

for mu in [0,3]:
    lightcuve_mu = lightcurve + mu
    bins = [mu+ DL, max(lightcurve_mu)+mu]
    detectionF = applyFormulaFromAbove(lightcurve_mu,bins)
    plot(bins,detectionF)
    for sigma in [0,3]:
        x = [0,10]
        plot(lognormal.pdf(x,mu,sigma))
```

I could also post a MWE python snipplet but I dont think it's a bug in the way the pdf or detection frequency are computed.

Comment: Could you please explain what is being plotted on these graphs?  What do the axes mean and what do the various colors represent?  How are these related to your partial description of your fitting procedure?  What does "mu" represent or mean?  What exactly is this "function of a set of medians and variances"?

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, but I strongly suspect there is a miscommunication between you and the documentation for `lognormal.pdf`.  How does that documentation describe the meanings of the parameters `mu` and `sigma`?  Are you *sure* your `mu` and `sigma` match that?  (In many implementations, these are the means and standard deviations of the *log* data, whereas it sounds--it's not too clear--that yours might be the medians and variances of the *data.*)

Comment: THANK YOU! Indeed I missunderstood the quantity mu in my lognormal pdf !